# Performing a text search in Mongo with a filter parameter

Tags: mongodb, text-search

## Aim

A MongoDB equivalent of this:
`SELECT (text_matches of "pies") FROM table WHERE (published = "true")`

## What I am trying

`db.find({ $text: { $search: searchTerm } }, {published: "true"})`

I can't work out where the `{published: "true"}` argument should be within the query, and I can't find any examples on the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/)

Answer (score -1):

`db.find({ published: "true", $text: { $search: searchTerm }})`